# bitcoind verifychain vs reindex

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, json-rpc, litecoin, database

actually this is not Bitcoin but Litecoin 0.13.2 on Linux Mint,

litecoind stopped with "bus error" just on start verifying blocks:

```
tail ~/.litecoin/debug.log
...
2017-05-06 21:15:26 Verifying last 24 blocks at level 3
2017-05-06 21:15:26 [0%]...2017-05-06 21:17:25
```

but just after this on the second try it started normally and I ran "litecoin-cli verifychain 3 0" and it passed successfully,

and now I'm not sure should I also run "litecoind -reindex"? or verifychain is enough to be shure that everything is ok?

what exactly verifychain does?